# How to send request payload as optional to the api call in React JS Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-functional-component, payload

I am trying to call API Using Axios in React JS. some times I will have a product ID and sometimes ill will not have a product ID. Currently, I am duplicating the code because of the product id.

```
This is API which is in common.js

fetchProducts: (payload) => put(`/products`, payload),

products.js

      if (productID) {
                        common.fetchProducts({
                            selectedItems: checkedItems,
                            productID: productID,
                        })
                            .then((resp) => {
                                console.log("Success",resp);
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                   console.log("Failure",err);
                            });
                    } else {
                        common.fetchProducts({
                            selectedItems: checkedItems,
                        })
                            .then((resp) => {
                                console.log("Success",resp);
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                   console.log("Failure",err);
                            });
                    }
```

and  products.js component I am having few more API calls because of this Optional parameter I am duplicating the code a lot. How can I  simplify this API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator?retiredLocale=vi) to reduce your code:

```
common.fetchProducts(
  productID
    ? {
        selectedItems: checkedItems,
        productID: productID,
      }
    : { selectedItems: checkedItems }
);
```